# deploy rails app to heroku failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

i'm trying to deploy my rails app to heroku for first time 
and my project already on github i tryed to do Deploy a GitHub branch from
 https://dashboard.heroku.com but it does't work .
does anyone know what is missing . thanks

```html
----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing i18n 0.7.0
       Installing rake 11.2.2
       Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
       Installing minitest 5.9.0
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
       Installing pkg-config 1.1.7
       Installing rack 1.6.4
       Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
       Installing arel 6.0.3
       Installing execjs 2.7.0
       Installing sass 3.4.22
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
       Installing multi_json 1.12.1
       Installing diff-lcs 1.2.5
       Using bundler 1.11.2
       Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
       Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
       Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
       Installing rspec-support 3.5.0
       Installing tilt 2.0.5
       Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions
       Installing rdoc 4.2.2
       Installing mime-types 3.1
       Installing autoprefixer-rails 6.3.7
       Installing uglifier 3.0.1
       Installing bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.2
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing sprockets 3.7.0
       Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3
       Installing rspec-core 3.5.2
       Installing rspec-expectations 3.5.0
       Installing rspec-mocks 3.5.0
       Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
       Installing activesupport 4.2.6
       Installing sdoc 0.4.1
       Installing mail 2.6.4
       Installing rspec 3.5.0
       Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
       Installing globalid 0.3.7
       Installing activemodel 4.2.6
       Installing jbuilder 2.6.0
       Installing activejob 4.2.6
       Installing activerecord 4.2.6
       Installing loofah 2.0.3
       Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
       Installing actionview 4.2.6
       Installing actionpack 4.2.6
       Installing actionmailer 4.2.6
       Installing railties 4.2.6
       Installing sprockets-rails 3.1.1
       Installing jquery-rails 4.1.1
       Installing font-awesome-rails 4.6.3.1
       Installing coffee-rails 4.1.1
       Installing sass-rails 5.0.6
       Installing rails 4.2.6
       Bundle complete! 20 Gemfile dependencies, 64 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Post-install message from rdoc:
       Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
       <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
       = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
       Bundle completed (29.90s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
 !
 !     Could not detect rake tasks
 !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
 !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
 !     rake aborted!
 !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- spec
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/Rakefile:4:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:686:in `raw_load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
 !     /tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
 !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
 !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
 !
/app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:102:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
and using the production group of your Gemfile.
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- spec
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:686:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/tmp/build_f91e85e485231755cd09d13fd6f480cf/ramyalzayat-Nuts-and-Tea-Splash-page-406e527/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:746:in `rake'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:131:in `log'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
 from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:70:in `run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:767:in `allow_git'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:98:in `block in compile'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
 from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:88:in `compile'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:49:in `block in compile'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
 from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:47:in `compile'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:38:in `block in compile'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
 from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:37:in `compile'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in `block in compile'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
 from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in `compile'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/compile:16:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:131:in `log'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/compile:15:in `block in <main>'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
 from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
 from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/compile:11:in `<main>'
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: and everytime if i want install gem i get the message
( ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the )

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **postgres** for your app on **heroku**

sqlite3 is not supported on heroku

Move `sqlite3` to `development` group

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

And add `pg` in `production` group

```
group :production, :test do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Comment: i did it but i got another thing sorry for that